# Are all strings of strings.xml are always available in heap memory in Android?

Tags: android, string

Suppose in an apk we have 1000 strings in strings.xml.

So when we run this app on device at that time all the strings are always available in heap memory. Or they loaded in memory when we call `getString()` method of Context to load the Strings.

Are all strings in the heap during runtime?

Comment: android compile  generate R file, this file contain string ids, they are all java constant. Read the AssetManager and StringBlock souce code may help u

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Android, is there a reason to use string resources for strings that are not going to be translated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32587336/in-android-is-there-a-reason-to-use-string-resources-for-strings-that-are-not-g)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16433112/185022

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308623/xml-string-resources-vs-java-constant-strings

Comment: Those links don't solve my problem. My only concern is whether all strings are in heap at a time?

Comment: They are called by their ids,similar to a button with no functions on a layout.Probably are in a heap at a time

Comment: I just don't understand those people who just keep pasting links rather than reading the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a great question. We can try to find the answer by studying the Android source code.

All calls to `getString()` get routed to the [following method](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/content/res/AssetManager.java#148) inside `android.content.res.AssetManager`:

```
/**
 * Retrieve the string value associated with a particular resource
 * identifier for the current configuration / skin.
 */
/*package*/ final CharSequence getResourceText(int ident) {
    synchronized (this) {
        TypedValue tmpValue = mValue;
        int block = loadResourceValue(ident, (short) 0, tmpValue, true);
        if (block >= 0) {
            if (tmpValue.type == TypedValue.TYPE_STRING) {
                return mStringBlocks[block].get(tmpValue.data);
            }
            return tmpValue.coerceToString();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

`loadResourceValue` is a native function and can be found in [android_util_AssetManager.cpp](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android_util_AssetManager.cpp#L880)

The native method calls `getResource()` inside the class `ResTable` [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4b1a8f46d6ec55796bf77fd8921a5a242a219278/include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h#L1625).

The constructor for `ResTable` calls `addInternal()` [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ff5c3ad08b186e71b7b1466c576c5d44f05746ca/libs/androidfw/ResourceTypes.cpp#L3648) which reads the resources for each package id in the app. This table is later used to perform lookups of resources.

So to answer your question, yes, all strings (and indeed all resources) are parsed from the filesystem and loaded into a lookup table in the native heap.